# Create personalized Python Library

Tags: python, python-packaging

I have few functions developed inside of jupyter notebook(.ipynb extension). Since all the functions are interrelated I would like create a python Library which will contain all these files. And I want to share it my company in such a way that. If they hit Pip install mylibrary, it will install the whole package. Since I do not know how I can create package insert the interrelated ipynb files, I just created a  dummy function and tried Few things :

My question without converting ipynb files to .py can I create python library. And how can I resolve the things that are mentioned in 1,2 ?

1. Installed the package from source directory to target directory in my local machine. But in target directory I am seeing egg-link file only and when I am trying to import mylibrary from target directory  it is showing 'no module named mylibrary'. I also set target directory as my pythonpath still seeing this issue.
2. Another option is publish the .tar.gz distribution file in my github release. When I am downloading the file and trying to install it using command prompt the error showing "https error 404 client error". Even though I tried to provide access token to ensure to connect it. Still it's showing error.

Comment: Have you looked into [nbdev](https://nbdev.fast.ai/)?